# How do I check if the rsyncd (server) is alive?

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple script to optimize some of my remote transfers. As the final check I'd like to add an option to check if the rsyncd (server) is alive.

What's the better way?

Check if its port is open? Do a dry-run? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could do some dry-run like:

```
rsync -n 192.168.1.200::
share           Public Share
```

and check the result. That "share" you see in the response was created just for test purpose in my rsyncd.conf on rsync test server.  Testing port open may respond success while the process is stalled.

Comment: So, do you think that the better way is do a dry-run? I don't see any way... thanks for help :-)

Comment: I'm not sure :-/ At this point I can use if [$? -ne 0] then/else... etc. without using dry-run

Comment: Note that if your rsync server is set not to list, you will get no response fro this command. If you add -vvv you will at least get some feedback.